# in postgresql 9.2, can hint optimization be used for partitions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

in a simple partitioned table:

```
-- note: no records stored in base, only inheritors of base
create table base(
   base_id       bigint,
   base_tp       char(3) not null,
   ... );

create table base_abc(
   base_id       bigserial   primary key,
   base_tp       default 'abc'
                 check( base_tp = 'abc' ),
   ...
) inherits( base );


create table base_efg(
   base_id       bigserial   primary key,
   base_tp       default 'efg'
                 check( base_tp = 'efg' ),
   ...
) inherits( base );
```

if the the where clause in a query were to use `base_tp`, eg,

```
select * from base where ... and base_tp='abc'
```

would under 9.2 the query be optimized to select only table `base_abc` or would it, as it does currently, query a `base`, `base_abc`, and `base_efg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this behaviour can be set via the `constraint_exclusion` config option.  If it's `on`, then only the partitions with matching constraint(s) will be accessed.  But you should be careful, and choose `partition` instead in order to avoid a heavy performance hit.  It's just the same considering partitioned tables, but leaves others unaffected.

Have a look at its [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION).

Comment: great reference.  seems to be just what doctor ordered.  thanks!